# How to fix my code to detect and remove properly outliers

Tags: octave, outliers, pattern-recognition

I am trying to detect and remove outliers from a dataset (1372 rows, 4 columns).

I wrote some code about finding them but I am not sure if this is the best way. Although I tried to remove them but instead of being removed the number 32 is replacing them. I can not understand why.

```
% Find outliers
meanValue = mean(data_banknote_authentication(:,1:4));
absoluteDeviation = abs(data_banknote_authentication(:,1:4) - meanValue);
mad = median(absoluteDeviation);
sensitivityFactor = 3 % I am not sure if this is correct
thresholdValue = sensitivityFactor * mad;
outlierIndexes = abs(absoluteDeviation) > thresholdValue
outliers = data_banknote_authentication(:,1:4)(outlierIndexes);
nonOutliers = data_banknote_authentication(:,1:4)(~outlierIndexes);

% Remove outliers
for i=1:1372
  for k=1:4
    if (outlierIndexes(i,k) == 1)
      data_banknote_authentication(i,k) = ' ';
      %data_banknote_authentication(i,k) = " ";
    endif
  endfor
endfor
```

I want to delete the outliers but the actual result is that in their position there is now the number 32. How can I remove them from the dataset?

Comment: you are putting a space so ASCII=32 . Try with `=[]` as null , but remember that will resize the `data_banknote_authentication` dimensions

Comment: I tried this       data_banknote_authentication(i,k) = [];
 but it gives me this error: a null assignment can only have one non-colon index

Comment: do you need to cancel all the 4 data of a row or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rmoutlier](https://octave.sourceforge.io/outliers/function/rmoutlier.html) function from octave
there are similer functions in matlab and python .
This function can remove the outliers or replace them with mean or median value.